# Get memory used by a process java

Tags: java

I know this question is a frequently one, however I checked some solutions from this site, but it seems like it didn't work for me.

So, I have written a small java program, and I want to know how much memory it consumes at different execution moments. I tried Runtime.getRuntime.total() and Runtime.getRuntime.free(), but I'm getting the (almost) same results each time.

I am not interested in how much memory is there available or used by the entire JVM, I want to know specifically for my java process.

Comment: For a small program, it may very well be so little memory that the amounts may indeed be very similar!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this will get you how much heap memory your process has used.

```
MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
heapMemoryUsage.getUsed();
```

you can also get all your memory pools and iterate through them to determine other memory usage

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memoryPoolMXBeans = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()
```

you could also use jvisualvm to interrogate your application.

Comment: It works apparently (also notice that is .getUsed() not .getused()).

Comment: Why is it necessary to call "heapMemoryUsage = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
heapMemoryUsage.getUsed();" before every measurement?

Comment: I see the above snippet is to get heap memory of a particular process, where do you provide your process id here ?

Answer (score 3):

> I am not interested in how much memory is there available or used by the entire JVM, I want to know specifically for my java process.

In a typical use-case, there is no real distinction between "the entire JVM" and "your Java process".  At least, not from the perspective of memory usage.

The thing is, everything that the JVM does, and every bit of memory it allocates is done at the behest of the application.  And every word of memory remains reachable because something in your application *might* use it at some point.

So really what you are asking for doesn't make a lot of sense.  And naturally, the information is not available.  Even if this did make sense, I don't know what you would gain by knowing what memory "belongs" to your application and what to the JVM.

Comment: Say I have several solutions to a problem (represented as java programs). I need to somehow compare them in terms of efficiency: execution speed and memory usage. That's why I needed to know a way to measure memory used. If you'd do either way, please tell.

Comment: You need to run each Java program in a separate JVM and compare the overall memory usages.  If the memory usage differences are "in the noise" compared with the overheads of the JVM, then you could argue that they don't matter.  Or you could (maybe should) increase the problem size to a point where the application's memory usage is significant.

Comment: I think it is still useful to know the total memory usage. For example, if your process is using a library that uses native memory (levelDB/ rocksDB come to mind), you want to know / alert if the total memory usage grows above a threshold. In that case, I care about total memory (heap + native).

Comment: @Jagadish - But that's not what the question is about.  The OP explicitly says he is NOT interested in what you said you are interested in : total memory.  Or at least, that is how I have chosen to interpret his Question.